# Related content to a specific content type in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a specific posttype like "productions". link example:

`example.com/productions/title1/ example.com/productions/title2/ example.com/productions/title3/` 
I would like to create related content for each title so that it has a url like:

`example.com/productions/title1/related/ example.com/productions/title2/related/ example.com/productions/title3/related/`

For example, it is done exactly as I want on this page:

`upfilm.pl/filmy/piepzyc-mickiewicza/
related:
upfilm.pl/filmy/piepzyc-mickiewicza/podobne/

`upfilm.pl/filmy/powzaniec-1863/ related:  upfilm.pl/filmy/powzaniec-1863/podobne/`

https://upfilm.pl/filmy/sami-swoi-poczatek/
related:
https://upfilm.pl/filmy/sami-swoi-poczatek/podobne/
`

How should I do it so that the url looks exactly like above, i.e., `example.com/productions/title1/related`

I tried to create a "Related" taxonomy in ACF and associate it with the Custom Post Type "Productions", but then my link just looks like `exmaple.com/related/` and it doesn't work as I would like.